# fsck at boot does it worth it?

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, fsck

With ext4 filesystems, I'm thinking about if it does worth it to put the fsck flags into my `/etc/fstab` file to fsck it every n boot. But the waiting time I spend does worth it? or the filesystem inconsistencies will be detected and I dont have to overcheck my filesystems?

so do I put the pass flag to 2 insthead of 0 into my `/etc/fstab` or not? only for my backup disc or even for my home partition?

`# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=e445ba7b-eced-41f6-b9e8-4c50e59d5fa3 /mnt/backups auto nosuid,nodev,x-gvfs-show,noatime 0 0`

Thx in advance